# postgresql объединение строк json в один объект

Tags: postgresql

результат моего запроса

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(sort, field_structure)
FROM _object_tpl_structure 
WHERE object_tpl_oid = '25bcdc48-a966-44fb-bc98-d8bedef12519'
```

возвращается ввиде строк

```
{"0": {"type": "int", "caption": "Возраст", "MaxLength": "0", "DefaultValue": ""}}
{"3": {"type": "dropdown", "Options": {"0": {"value": "2", "active": "1", "caption": "Ж"}, "1": {"value": "1", "active": "0", "caption": "М"}}, "caption": "Пол"}}
```

как мне свести полученные строки в json-объект вида?

```
{"0": {"type": "int", "caption": "Возраст", "MaxLength": "0", "DefaultValue": ""}}, {"3": {"type": "dropdown", "Options": {"0": {"value": "2", "active": "1", "caption": "Ж"}, "1": {"value": "1", "active": "0", "caption": "М"}}, "caption": "Пол"}}
```

пробовал через `string_agg`  - получается чистая строка, `json_agg` - массив, а мне нужен чистый объект, кортеж, я правильно называю?

Answer (score 1):

Решение простое:

```
 SELECT json_object_agg(sort, field_structure) 
 FROM _object_tpl_structure 
 WHERE object_tpl_oid = '25bcdc48-a966-44fb-bc98-d8bedef12519'
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/330268)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko почему вы считаете, что решение недостаточно исчерпывающее? Оно работает - работает, решает проблему поставленную в вопросе.

Comment: @AntonSorokin Видимо я оформил неправильно, я написал более подробный ответ :)

Comment: @AntonSorokin, когда я его проверял, то он был другим) сейчас ответ вполне себе ничего :)

Comment: дада, я исправился :)